# Should I copy files from bower_components of reference them there?

Tags: javascript, bower, bower-install

After installing `BackboneJS`, `jQuery` etc I have a very large `bower_components` directory.

```
├───.idea
│   ├───runConfigurations
│   └───scopes
└───app
    ├───bower_components
    │   ├───backbone
    │   ├───jquery
    │   │   ├───dist
    │   │   └───src
    │   │       ├───ajax
    │   │       │   └───var
    │   │       ├───attributes
    │   │       ├───core
    │   │       │   └───var
    │   │       ├───css
    │   │       │   └───var
    │   │       ├───data
    │   │       │   └───var
    │   │       ├───effects
    │   │       ├───event
    │   │       ├───exports
    │   │       ├───manipulation
    │   │       │   └───var
    │   │       ├───queue
    │   │       ├───sizzle
    │   │       │   ├───dist
    │   │       │   └───test
    │   │       │       ├───data
    │   │       │       └───unit
    │   │       ├───traversing
    │   │       │   └───var
    │   │       └───var
    │   └───underscore
    ├───css
    └───js
```

What is best practice to reference these?  e.g directly, Grunt task to copy bits to the main app, or put the `bower_componects` inside the `~/app` directory?

Comment: O dang, you manually typed that whole tree? So pro!

Comment: @Rudie No, that would be insane.  I just used `tree` in PowerShell and then, copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

Don't copy them over to your app - that completely defies the intent of a package manager like Bower! By doing so, you'd take control over these files away from your package manager - and then you're left in the same state as before, manually having to copy over files every time with an update of these dependencies.

Just reference the files inside the `bower_components/` directory directly (in your HTML, most likely). If you don't like that location or name, you can have bower put your components some place else, see `.bowerrc` doc: http://bower.io/docs/config/

---

I can think of a use for only using specific files from your bower_components directory - but **only at build time**:

If you write a grunt task that runs only at deploy time and strips away all unused files from the `bower_components` directory, that of course makes sense and does not go against the idea of a package manager, because it only happens on each deploy, a point when the package manager has no responsibilities.

The only problem you might get with this approach is if you have it end up copying files over to a different directory - because then you'd have to change the references to all files from `bower_components` before deploying, too. The easy solution is to not duplicate files, but instead, only delete the ones you *don't need*.

Comment: A Grunt task would have been how I handled it.  I'm loathed to have that much noise in my application.

Comment: The question is really what the 'it' is that you're handling here. For most cases, doing anything manually with the files supplied by a package manager, again, defies the point of using one in the first place. If you're serving it as a website - obviously having this 'noise' won't generate you any additional traffic.

Comment: I didn't want extra files deployed because I don't want to temp anyone to reference them.  Basically, I like to lean the production code as lean as I can.

Comment: You also most likely don't want to check in these files in source control. I'm not sure what you mean by others referencing them - again, what's your specific use case here?

Comment: There are some files and directories I don't want to deploy the bower_components file.  I like the convention of a file system similar to `~/app/assets/js/...`, I'd prefer it if that directory only had files the page was using.  `bower_components` has, for example, testing suites.  I'd like to not have them in me app directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave them in `bower_components` and refer proper files inside your index.html file. You can do this manually, or use tools like [grunt wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep) to do this for you automatically.